# Jackson's `Visibility.Any` performance

Tags: java, performance, reflection, jackson, lombok

Using Jackson with Lombok's `@Accessors(fluent=true)` requires to add `@JsonAutoDetect(Visibility.Any)` annotation:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(fluent=true)
public class Pojo{
  private String fieldOne;
  private String fieldTwo;
}
```

I am curious of the performance of `Visibilty.Any`. Does it use reflection or compile time hooks are added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jackson` uses reflection plus caching to implement serialisation and deserialisation processes anyway. Using this annotation does not add any noticeable performance cost. For more info, take a look how it is implemented: [JsonAutoDetect.java](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect.java). It allows you to change default visibility configuration for fields, getters, setters, creators and constructors.

Comment: could you also add link to some code snippet where the specific annotation processing  is happening?

Comment: @AbhinavAtul, If you want to find out more info about it check [AnnotationIntrospector](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector.html) class and [findAutoDetectVisibility](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector.html#findAutoDetectVisibility-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker-) method. You can open this class in your IDE and find all usages.